# Internal Server Error on php submit with MySQL commands

Tags: php, mysql

I get an internal server error with the following code... any suggestions:

```
<form name="user" action="this.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="" />

<input type="submit" name="" id="" value="Edit Page"  />    
</form>
```

There is no other code on the page, and it self submits fine UNLESS I place a MySQL query inside the text field, such as SELECT s FROM d WHERE 1=1

Then I get the following error:

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@test.info and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I do have some .htaccess rules going on, but I don't know how that would effect a query that doesn't do anything or go anywhere...

Comment: How does the MySQL statement get put into the .php page?

Comment: If I type in the SQL statement in the input box. I think it's a server config issue, but I don't know where to begin to look.

Comment: Unrelated (or only marginally related, if the mod_security guess is correct, as I suspect), but you need to `htmlspecialchars` your echoing of `PHP_SELF`, the same as any other string you write into HTML. Otherwise you risk breakages and cross-site-scripting errors (even when the annoying and ineffective mod_security is turned on).

Comment: @bobince - even when i remove PHP_SELF, and specify the page, the error still occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be rule of the evil **mod_security**. Are you on shared hosting? Generally you can disable all the module or specific rules via *.htaccess* file.

Comment: You were right, it was a mod_security issue. Just had to whitelist the files being affected.

Answer (score 0):

The first place to look is your webserver log files.

The second place to look is [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php) as I'd guess you are just stuffing whatever the user hands you into the SQL server without any sanitizing.

Comment: I'm not submitting anything to the SQL server. That's the weird part. There's not even a connection to the SQL server in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Before execute, dump the content of $_POST[];

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

In development enviorment, it's good to enable error displaying:

```
display_errors(1);
```

Or in php.ini:

```
display_errors = On;
```

Answer (score -1):

With the limited information provided, what it sounds like is that you are sending a malformed sql query somehow, and you aren't catching the error returned by the mysql server.  You need to look at what you are sending, and handle mysql errors.

Comment: Nothing is going to a SQL server... at least not through the script. The code that I showed is all that is being sent. Nothing else exists in the script.