# Internal Server Error when accessing MySQL database via MySQL_Connect

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, internal-server-error

Thanks ahead of time for reading my post.

I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error when I successfully access my database via MySQL_Connect. If I put in incorrect credentials for my database I successfully display an error message when I visit my "loginapp.php" file on my site.

I am currently using iPage as a web host.

This is the code in my "loginapp.php"

```html
<?php

//ob
ob_start();

//session
session_start();

//connect
$error = 'Could not connect to the database';
mysql_connect('MyDataBase.ipagemysql.com', 'MyBase','MyPass') or die($error);
mysql__select_db('MyDatabase') or die($error);

//include functions.php phpbb script
require 'forum/includes/auth/loginuser.php';

?>

<form action="loginapp.php" method="POST">
Username:<br />
<input type="text" name="username"><p />
Password:<br />
<input type="password" name="password"><p />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in">

</form>
```

I'm aware that my .htaccess file might somehow be blocking external access to MySQL databases, but I am not very familiar with .htaccess...

I'm pretty sure its not a coding problem, because I only get the 500 error when I put in the correct credentials for my database.

Thanks
Scott

Comment: .htaccess never block access to MySQL databases

Comment: `mysql__select_db` shouldn't it be `mysql_select_db` ? Use `mysqli` , `mysql` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Try to avoid using my_sql , use PDO or my_sqli and also  you should declare the session_start() immediately after your <?php

Answer (score 0):

Disable mod_security in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>

  SecFilterEngine Off

  SecFilterScanPOST Off

</IfModule>
```

**Note : "mysql__select_db" should be "mysql_select_db"**

**Source :**

[Internal Server Error on php submit with MySQL commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983013/internal-server-error-on-php-submit-with-mysql-commands)

[How can I disable mod_security in .htaccess file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928360/how-can-i-disable-mod-security-in-htaccess-file)